# Does a self adjoint Operator in a Hilbert space which is possibly unbounded, admit only countably many Eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

If $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ is a selfadjoint Operator and possibly unbounded, $H$ a seperable Hilbert space. Does $A$ admit a non empty, atmost countable, pointspectrum?

I understand that, if there are finitely many, or no eigenvalues then there only countably many.

So lets just assume for now there are infinitely many of them.

Then there eigenspaces are orthogonal and we could decompose $H$ in a orthogonal sum of the nullspace and all the eigenspaces and some remainder.

i.e. $H=\overline{U}\oplus U^\perp$ where $U:=\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace}$ $\mathrm{ker}(\lambda- A)$

But why do we know that there are countably many eigenvalues and not overcountably many?

And how can we be sure that $\sigma_p(A)\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Yes. Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal (the usual proof works although you may have to fuss with considerations about the domain in the unbounded case). Feel free to answer your own question with those details!

Comment: The Całego transform of $A$ is a unitary operator with the same collection of eigenvectors. Hence there are only countably many of them. In this way we can omit the domain problems.

Comment: @leslietownes: There aren't even any domain issues, are there?  An eigenvector is in the domain by definition, so if $u,v$ are two eigenvectors the identity $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, Av \rangle$ is literally true, and that's all we need for the proof of orthogonality.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc did you mean the "Cayley transform"? Searching for Calego transform yields only "Since 1941, Calego has been the top distributor of soft and hard sided luggage"

Comment: @s.harp Sorry for the misprint  I meant Cayley. Although there are no serious obstacles while considering unbounded selfadjoint, or just symmetric operator $A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Okay, but why does a unitary operator has atmost countably many eigenvalues?

Comment: Thank you guys, for all youre help. I edited the question to point out my actually concerns a bit more.

Comment: @s.harp The eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues of a unitary operator are orthogonal to each other, as it holds for any normal operator

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yeah I know, my comment was only about the unknown transform.

Comment: @s.harp Sorry, my comment should have been addressed to MackeyTopology

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I see. It now became all crystal clear to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question, we can certainly have $\sigma_p(A)=\emptyset$, even in the bounded case. A typical example is $T_x:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ given by $T_xf(x)=xf(x)$.

Having uncountably many eigenvalues would imply uncountably many orthogonal eigenvectors, violating the separability assumption.

Comment: Thank you, this answers one part of my question. So there is no garuanty, the point spectrum might be empty. But how does it exaclty violate the separability condition.  $U$ has a overcountable Hamelbasis. Any Banach space has that or is finite dimensional. Where is is the exact contradiction we get?

Comment: Ah, this is the issue. The basis we refer to when they say "a separable hilbert space has a countable basis" is a Schauder basis, not a Hamel basis.

Comment: Thank you for youre answer, but that was not my issue. I mean how do you get an exact contradiction from $U$ having an uncountable basis of orthogonal eigenvectors?

Comment: Ok, suppose $U$ has an uncountable list of orthogonal vectors. They're at a distance $\sqrt{2}$ away from each other. By separability, you may find a vector from a countable list within $\sqrt{2}/2$ of each of these vectors. They are distinct, contradicting countability.

Comment: Okay, this makes perfectly sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @MackeyTopology I'm glad it helped, happy studying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147520/discussion-between-mackeytopology-and-operatorerror).